# Back pack 5- Validation mark as required a field with value on it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I have a CRUD controller created via BackPack and it works correctly, but for some reason my RequestValidation says that a **field is required when it has a value** on it, this happens when I try to edit a line that haves all values. This "error" only occurs with the field "link".

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\ProductDocumentRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class ProductDocumentCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class ProductDocumentCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\ProductDocument::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/product-document');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('product document', 'product documents');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('title');
        CRUD::column('reference');
        CRUD::column('original_link')->label('Archivo');
        CRUD::column('machine');
        CRUD::column('machine_type');
        CRUD::column('date');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(ProductDocumentRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('title');
        CRUD::field('reference');
        CRUD::field('link')->type('upload')->upload(true)->label('Archivo');
        CRUD::field('machine');
        CRUD::field('machine_type');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']));
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(ProductDocumentRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('title');
        CRUD::field('reference');
        CRUD::field('link')->type('upload')->upload(true)->label('Archivo');
        CRUD::field('machine');
        CRUD::field('machine_type');
    }
}
```

My ProductDocumentRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProductDocumentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'reference' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'link' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:10000',
            'machine' => 'required_without:machine_type',
            'machine_type' => 'required_without:machine',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem I have:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting element in your browser on your Archivo field and checking that the input attribute name equals 'link'?

Comment: Maybe the link field shouldn't be required on update, only create? Otherwise you will have to manually select a file every time.

Comment: yes it has a value, but maybe you are right and I don need to put the field required in update

Comment: where is your link form?